# Ruby on Rails Undefined method 'course_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a simple student planner app. If I try to view the course (course#show) assignments before adding an assignment to the course I get an error thrown instead of an empty list with just the course_name printed at the top.

The error reads:
"undefined method `course_name' for nil:NilClass"

My course#show page is where the error is being thrown on line 2:

```
<div class='container text-center'>
 <h2> <%= @course.course_name %> </h2>
 <% @course.assignments.all.each do |assignment| %>
  <%= assignment.title %>, <%= assignment.course.course_name %>, <%= assignment.due_date %> 
  <br>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

My courses_controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @course = Course.new
 end
 def create
  @course = Course.create(course_params)
  if @course.save
   redirect_to student_courses_path(@student)
  else
   render :new
  end
 end
def index
  student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
  @courses = Course.all
end
def show
  student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
  @course = student.courses.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
def edit
end
def update
end
private
  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:course_name)
  end
end
```

Course model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :students, through: :assignments
 validates :course_name, presence: true
end
```

Any thoughts on what's going on? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You should display assignments only if they are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@course` come from your `show` controller action, where you're trying to find it by its ID, but you're not checking if you found it or not.

In the case a `Course` is mandatory for a `Student`, add a presence validation on `:course_id` on the `Student` model, and when you create the student, you'll get an error when no course is assigned.

In the case `Course` is not mandatory for a `Student`, you could add a `<% if @course %>` block in your view file, and in the `<% else %>` part showing a message. For example:

```
<% if @course %>
  <div class='container text-center'>
    <h2><%= @course.course_name %></h2>
    <% @course.assignments.all.each do |assignment| %>
      <%= assignment.title %>, <%= assignment.course.course_name %>, <%= assignment.due_date %> 
      <br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class='container text-center'>
    <p>This student has no course yet.</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @ZedTuX !! I took your advice and added the if/else and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Also modify your html code as below and show assignments only if they are present.

Also no need to write **.all** on associated objects.

```
<% if @course %>
  <div class='container text-center'>
    <h2><%= @course.course_name %></h2>
    <% if @course.assignment.any? %>
      <% @course.assignments.each do |assignment| %>
        <%= assignment.title %>, <%= assignment.course.course_name %>, <%= assignment.due_date %> 
        <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class='container text-center'>
    <p>This student has no course yet.</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```